# Loading problem with circuit simulation

Tags: transistors, capacitor, switches, ltspice, load

**EDIT #1**

So I understand now the phenomenon that is happening.
Taking operational stage 2 Switch is OFF.
[image]
So there are the 2 cases discussed.

- RL = ∞ (exaggerated scenario) the current I1 >> I2 so the capacitor C1 charges to the level of supply voltage.
- RL = 50ohms the current I1 << I2 so the capacitor C1 cannot charge to the supply voltage level.

Now part of the question is answered, but I still do not have a solution...
How can I solve that problem?

**Initial question**
I have this simulation of a pulse generating circuit. I try different loads and I get different results. I am hoping that someone can explain the phenomenon I am seeing in the simulations and maybe point out ways to solve it.

Here is the circuit; I do not have a load attached to the output, so I assume that LTSpice sees it as a open circuit.

[image]

Here is the simulated result; [image]

Now when I change the load I get different results, and this is something that I do not understand and I hope someone can explain to me.

[image]

The simulation with a 50ohms resistor;

[image]

I tried it with a 10k resistor as well.
[image]

Here is the simulation for that. [image]

And finally when I put an absurdly high resistor value at the end I get the following ; [image]

[image]

The result is basically the same as the "no load" condition which makes sense as LTSpice sees both as very high impedance.

I even tried to understand the operating stages of the circuit, but I still cannot grasp the phenomenon occurring.

During the first operational stage I assume that the switch is ON, so the current is conducted through the switch to ground, so the load potential is close to zero.

[image]

The second operational stage. During the second operational stage I assume that the switch is OFF, so the current is conducted to the capacitor  so the load potential raises.

[image]

I will provide the .asc

Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 16 -208 -64 -208
WIRE 192 -208 96 -208
WIRE 224 -208 192 -208
WIRE -64 -160 -64 -208
WIRE 192 -80 192 -208
WIRE 192 80 192 0
WIRE 336 80 192 80
WIRE 400 80 336 80
WIRE 560 80 464 80
WIRE 336 112 336 80
WIRE 192 128 192 80
WIRE 560 128 560 80
WIRE -112 176 -128 176
WIRE 16 176 -32 176
WIRE 16 208 16 176
WIRE 144 208 16 208
WIRE 336 224 336 176
WIRE 560 224 560 208
WIRE 192 256 192 224
WIRE -128 288 -128 176
FLAG -128 368 0
FLAG 192 256 0
FLAG 560 80 V_out
FLAG 336 224 0
FLAG -64 -160 0
FLAG 224 -208 High_voltage
FLAG 560 224 0
SYMBOL voltage -128 272 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(10 0 1u 5u 5u 185u 200u)
SYMBOL res -16 160 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 47
SYMBOL nmos 144 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value STW11NM80
SYMBOL res 176 -96 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 320 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1n
SYMBOL cap 464 64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL voltage 112 -208 R90
WINDOW 0 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 500
SYMBOL res 544 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R_LOAD
SYMATTR Value 100000k
TEXT -162 412 Left 2 !.tran 2m

Comment: The circuit appears to be doing exactly what it looks like it should do. What I don't know is what **you** are expecting it to do. Haven't we been here before Dimitar: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653482/circuit-simulation-for-electrical-fast-transient-generator ?

Comment: I wanted to start over and get a clean simulation, with a lot less building blocks. I just want to understand the behaviour of the circuit. 

I thought of you and you ;) so I went over to a previous question similar to this one and no one really explained what I do not understand. 

What I do not understand is why is the output voltage fluctuating between 0 and -81V and for the other simulation 250 and -250V. 

If to you it makes sense what the circuit is doing can you maybe explain it and suggest a method to "stabilize it" to the same output as the " 100000k" load.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the voltage **across** the 100nF capacitor in each version of your circuit?

Comment: @SteKulov Interesting suggestion.
I just did that and for the 100000k load the voltage variation is in the mVs. For the 50ohms load it varies from 0 to 90V. 
I am not sure what I can do with that information.

Comment: @Andyaka what should I do if no one is replying?

Comment: Well, I can't reply because you haven't told me what you are expecting the circuit to do. See my top comment.. And without knowing what you want it to do I can't tell you why your simulation is wrong = I can't help.

Comment: @Andyaka I made an edit explaing that i understand what phenomenon im seeing when varying the load resistance. My goal would be to charge the capacitor C1 to the high voltage level pretty muhh regardless of the load.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what the circuit is expected to do. You can explain that without referring to any capacitor or transistor.

Comment: Well basically it should be a high voltage pulse generator. The goal would be to take the DC voltage and by switching on and off to have high voltage pulses that are subsequently injected to a load (I/O cable, Power cable, etc..)

Comment: @Andyaka should I change the question? I am not getting many views or responses... 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your question is now a historical mix of the original question, self-made answers (which should be in answers and not dumped into the question) all jumbled together. This means that anyone coming newly to this question is just confused about what you are asking and will soon lose interest and move-on. Neither does you question state what you are trying to design. You mention it just above but, clearly, a new viewer won't get that far.

Comment: In my opinion you should begin again but provide a link to this question just so that folk are aware of the history behind a new question. I think you are trying to produce ESD pulses of some form so, start by explaining that. Then show the **voltage** waveform you are trying to generate. Then show equivalent circuits from the specification the pulse is meant to conform to. Then ask how these pulses might be simulated and forget about trying to make a design.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I appreciate it.