# Electrical fast transient waveform (switching circuit) load

Tags: ltspice, simulation, high-voltage, switching, transient

I am simulating a circuit to model the EN 61000-4-4 waveform for electrical fast transients using LTspice.  The idea is to have the generator for some in house testing.

[Here is an old question I have that shows some of the progress done so far.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659029/loading-problem-with-circuit-simulation)

The waveform is a high voltage low energy pulse. Here is what the waveform looks like:

[image]

I do not need the exact waveform specification as this is needed for in house testing.

The standard provides with a very simplified equivalent circuit, but it is so simplified it is useless:

[image]

I want to model the switching circuit.
The idea is to feed the switching circuit with a high DC voltage and by performing ON/OFF function to generate these high voltage, low current pulses that will be then injected to various loads (I/O cables, power cables,etc.)

Here is a block diagram for that:

[image]

I have already modeled the circuit in LTspice, and simulated a few results that can be seen in the previous post. For simplicity I will reattach it here.

Here is the switching circuit:

[image]

It does not work as intended because the load R_LOAD presents a small resistance compared to the C1 capacitor, the capacitor does not charge to the input voltage level.

Here are some simulations:

This is the ideal result that I would like to get for all loads:

[image]

Here is the result for a 50 ohm  load:

[image]

Comment: Ditch C1 entirely and make C2 a lot larger.

Comment: can you explain your reasoning ?

Comment: Better still, make C2 smaller so that it sets the pulse width as specified.

Comment: @TimWilliams with or without C1?

Comment: The simplified schematic will work (and actually is of great use) but, you need to provide values for the components. Is 1 kV the peak open-circuit voltage output you want? Your circuit will never give you a rise time of 6 ns. You need to ditch your circuit idea as I told you before (*and forget about trying to make a design*) but, you didn't listen and now you have an answer pointing out the weaknesses in your design and that's not going to help you here. I do wish folk would listen.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes ideally 1kV is the peak open-circuit voltage. I mentioned in the question that I do not need the exact pulse waveform shape.

Comment: You need to read my full comment very carefully.

Comment: So your suggestion is to figure out the values of the simplified schematic ?

Comment: That would be a very good starting point but, the standard should tell you those values.

Comment: C1 does nothing but waste power in the transistor, and precious current capacity. What is it supposed to be representing? The correct transformation of the original circuit is to swap Cc and Switch, not move Switch in parallel. Where are Rs and Rm?

Comment: Funny enough it does not... Life would have been very easy if it did,
it says that Cd is 10nF and the load is 50 ohms.

Comment: @Andyaka The standard does not provide a realization actually, probably because it's a complicated enough system that high pulse components and wave effects are relevant, so only the cartoon model is provided. I expect most manufacturers use a hydrogen thyratron, but I haven't opened up a generator to see, personally.

Comment: @TimWilliams I bow to your knowledge on this subject. A 6 ns rise time is really problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C1 is not doing anything in your circuit, in fact it's actively harming its operation. When you turn on the MOSFET, C1 just discharges through the FET, heating it up. It does not transfer any energy to the output. You should therefore remove C1.

C2 actually stores the energy that gets delivered to the load. Its "left side" charges up to 500V, while the "right side" stays at 0V. When the MOSFET pulls the left side to ground, the right side will then be at -500V, producing your desired transient (although negative, but this shouldn't matter). C2 then slowly discharges, producing the decaying waveform.

Your MOSFET is also currently not switching on fast enough for the transient to reach its maximum voltage - the voltage across C2 decays already while the FET is still turning on. As a result, you have to switch your FET faster, which you can do by decreasing the value of R1, or maybe even removing it entirely.

So, in short: Remove C1, replace R1 with a short, and then adjust the value of C2 until you get the desired waveform (with the load in place).

If you actually need the full 1kV output voltage, you'll have to use  a different MOSFET, i.e. a silicon carbide FET. Note, though, that a rise time of 10ns or less is more than just unrealistic with this circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I can settle with a slower rise time. I do not need the exact parameters as the standard.